# python file executables

Tags: python

I have python 3.2 and 2.7 both installed.

When I tried to run `filename.py`, the command prompt opened for a second and disappeared, and nothing ran.

I also have a problem running from the idle for python. Maybe it is because of the environment variable? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

First, do you have something like `input("THE END")` or `os.system("pause")` at the end of your script ? With this, the prompt should not dissapear and you may see what is wrong.

For your executable, you should avoid the problem by typing the full path for the Python interpreter you want to use :

```
MyPrompt> C:\Python32\python.exe filename.py
```

Comment: I can't even execute the helloworld.py , not to mention other complex programs. I can only execute them by opeing them from idle and pressing F5.